# Using .html file to run a Javascript experiment

Tags: javascript, html, mechanicalturk, psychopy

I originally hosted an experiment on Mechanical Turk, written in one html file. It uses html, javascript, and CSS.

I want to host this experiment using Pavlovia. Pavlovia hosts javascript experiments. Is it possible to use the code I already have on Pavlovia? I don't quite understand the interface yet, so I'm unsure how to test it out.

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, training and coffee.  Perhaps you just need a bit more time to get to know Pavlovia's interface.

Comment: This question would probably be better addressed to the support forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org